# Python sorting list of dictionary sort by key with multiple decimals

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sorting

I have a list of dictionary named `code[]` which has values

```
[{'sectionnumber': '1010.1.9.1', ...},
{'sectionnumber': '1010.1.9.2', ...}
{'sectionnumber': '1010.1.9', ...},
{'sectionnumber': '1010.1.9.10', ...}]
```

and I want to sort them by `sectionnumber`. I tried using :

```
codelist = sorted(codelist, key=lambda codelist:codelist["sectionnumber"])
```

but it returns

```
[{'sectionnumber': '1010.1.9', ...},
{'sectionnumber': '1010.1.9.1', ...}
{'sectionnumber': '1010.1.9.10', ...},
{'sectionnumber': '1010.1.9.2', ...}]
```

when it supposed to be

```
[{'sectionnumber': '1010.1.9', ...},
{'sectionnumber': '1010.1.9.1', ...}
{'sectionnumber': '1010.1.9.2', ...},
{'sectionnumber': '1010.1.9.10', ...}]
```

Comment: Hello,  regarding `sorted(codelist, key=lambda codelist:codelist["sectionnumber"])`: this line is technically correct, but I strongly encourage you **not** to name every variable with the same name. Here the list of pairs is named `codelist` and the pairs are named `codelist` too. I suggest using different names for different things. For instance `codelist = sorted(codelist, key=lambda x: x["sectionnumber"])`